# Pexpect equivalent for java?

Tags: java, python, pexpect

Is there a pexpect equivalent for java? I know that I could replicate the functionality by using commons exec or processbuilder and redirecting stdin/stdout and then parsing the streams etc etc But, my question is, is there a plug-and-play equivalent for that?

What I would like would be to run interactive command line programs like I do in python. A small example is:

```
def start_binary(input):
   shell_cmd = 'grep '+input+' file4.dat >> file3.dat'
   grep = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', shell_cmd])
   grep.expect(pexpect.EOF)
   shell_cmd = './myProg -c'
   myProg = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash', ['-c', shell_cmd])
   myProg.expect('Next DATA file')
   file_list = ['file1.dat', 'file2.dat', 'file3.dat']
   for this_file in file_list:
      myProg.sendline(this_file)
   myProg.sendline()
   return myProg
```

And then I use myProg in an interactive way (sending commands, getting/parsing results, etc). I can get the results between two calls through myProg.before, etc.

Is there a package that offers the same functionality in the same easy way in java?

Comment: Probably not without native code; Java's subprocess handling is extremely weak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Google search for "java expect" found [expect4j](http://code.google.com/p/expect4j/) as the first item in the list and ExpectJ as the second item listed.

Comment: Sorry for not knowing what to search. Try searching "Java pexpect" or "java pexpect equivalent" or "java run interactive console programs" and tell me in which page you find the "first item". If I knew it was so "simple", I wouldn't have made a question out of it.

You should put in the rules: "If there is a chance by using a keyword in google to find it, don't ask it!"

Thanks for the hint anyway. I'll try not to ask any othe "not constructive" questions...